# Python Port Scanner shows open ports on non-existing host

Tags: python, networking, port

In my Python port scanner I have the following method to scan one specific port:

```
def portscan(port):
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((target, port))
    return True
except:
    return False
```

When I scan my localhost or an existing host in my network, it only returns True when the port is really open. But as soon as I scan an address that is not existing it always tells me that the same ports are open (25, 110, 119, 143, 465).

Why is that and how can I change it?

Comment: `def portscan(port):` vs `def portscan(target, port):` ...misstake?

Comment: @s3n0 no target is a global variable. This is just a piece of the code

Comment: The error may be theoretically also in the network interface or network elements (existence of a proxy server, bad router, etc.). Or, the `socket` module keeps track of the most recently detected targets and uses this cache? There will probably be a global variable error (change or refuse change). I did not see your entire code so I can not figure out where there might be a mistake. Try to add `global target`,  to the beginning of the function. Or, try to add `print(target)` into function - to verify the content of the global variable `target`.

Comment: We need a baseline test: 1) run 'netstat' or 'ss' to see listening tcp ports on your machine 2) run your program on your connected IP address (192.168.x.x, etc) 3) if you get the same rules as above run your program as admin and turn off your firewall and try again.